# How to override physical marker in vuforia AR Camera in runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, unity3d-2dtools

How can I override the physical marker in unity to just make the physical marker invisible in camera while detecting any object.

Like in this video:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=R_F1LvK5gCk
And many other videos.

Comment: Add a script on marker, set a public boolean, on enable find a way to execute SetActive(boolean) ?

Comment: Are u saying to apply shader? Did u see the video they just make invisible physical marker.

Comment: First, in the video provided, the marker may not be hiden bacause the model is shown above . Second, where did you see me talking about shader? I just tell you to set the gameobject inactive. And thinking about it, you'd better set the mesh renderer to false

Answer (score 1):

This maybe isn't the correct answer but, I'll put my ideas here because sadly it doesn't fit in the comment section.

I just watch the video and some of the reels they show as his works.

First, yes, in deed they make the marker a sort of invisible marker, but if you look closely, like a 0.25 speed and pushing space bar very fast to look it in slowmo, you can see a kind of "artifact" in between the girl's fingers that makes me think there's no invisible marker but a texture that are covering the marker. Maybe a cylinder that gets his texture from the video camera input.

Now, how I do that?
There are several ways to get the pixels from the webcamera, even [Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixels.html) has one function. The trouble is, I dont want all the pixels but a little tiny part of the camera render, specifically the one's around my marker.

In my experience, and in his examples, they are using OpenCV, another unity plugin, so they can track anything, from faces, hands, or markers, so I can't be quite sure they are using Vuforia alone or in combination.

My idea is, with OpenCV you can catch your marker and his contour, then ask for the pixels outside the contour of your marker, those pixels will be the skin tone of the person and latter apply them as a texture over some plane or 3d model that can cover your marker. You can have the pixels at right side and left side of the marker and use a average function betwen them so it could look nice or if you like the adventures you can try to use some kind of digital images processing method to get bether results.

I'm not sure if you can have the pixels arround a marker just using just Vuforia. Honestly I've never try it before.

Well, that's my idea.
If you can get it better I'll like to hear about it.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful

Comment: Sorry but, as I said, this is just an idea; I know you can achieve this because I used to work on some projects with Vuforia and OpenCV with Unity but for your specific case I'm afraid that I don't have any recipe. My only sugestion is to go to the Vuforia and OpenCV forums.